# Show other slides in between items

Tags: beamer

I need to have a list of items and after showing each item, jump to a slide that explains it with a picture, and get back to the original slide.
I know how to do it if there's only one jump, but not if there are more. I need something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame[label=frame1]{
   \frametitle{First Headline}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<1> point1    % go to show pic 1
      \item<2> point2    % come back here, then go to show pic2
      \item<3> point3    % come back here, then go to show pic3
      \item<4> point4    % come back here
   \end{itemize}
}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/Pic1}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{frame1}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/Pic2}
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>{frame1}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/Pic3}
\end{frame}

\againframe<4>{frame1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? E.g. showing only the first overlay at the beginning?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=frame1]
   \frametitle{First Headline}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item<1> point1    % go to show pic 1
      \item<2> point2    % come back here, then go to show pic2
      \item<3> point3    % come back here, then go to show pic3
      \item<4> point4    % come back here
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{frame1}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>{frame1}

\begin{frame}
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\againframe<4>{frame1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only jumps to pic1 after the first item, then goes back and shows the rest of the items, then goes to show other pictures. I need this sequence: item1 -> pic1 -> item2 -> pic2 -> item3 -> pic3.

Comment: @ozaroos But isn't this exactly what my answer does?